# How do I use the Compass background-with-css2-fallback mixin?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

How do I use the Compass [background-with-css2-fallback](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/#mixin-background-with-css2-fallback) mixin with a fallback?

I'm specifically wanting to be able to set a default background color for older versions of IE.

Here's what I'm currently trying, but IE8 and below don't seem to recognize it:

```
div {
  background: #0E1B31;
  @include background-with-css2-fallback(linear-gradient(top, #0E1B31, #0A1322));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of `background-with-css2-fallback` is to save you from writing the `background: #0E1B31;` line. You would use it like this:

```
div {
  @include background-with-css2-fallback(linear-gradient(top, #0E1B31, #0A1322), #0E1B31);
}
```

What you will get is this:

```
div {
  background: #0e1b31;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #0e1b31), color-stop(100%, #0a1322)), #0e1b31;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0e1b31, #0a1322), #0e1b31;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0e1b31, #0a1322), #0e1b31;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0e1b31, #0a1322), #0e1b31;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0e1b31, #0a1322), #0e1b31;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0e1b31, #0a1322), #0e1b31;
}
```

I think you really just want:

```
div {
  background: #0E1B31;
  @include background(linear-gradient(top, #0E1B31, #0A1322));
}
```

It will work the the same, be more readable, and output less code. You can change the include to `background-image` if you want the color to stick around behind the gradient in newer browsers.

Comment: `background-with-css2-fallback` actually doesn't output what you're showing. Here's what gets output for me: https://gist.github.com/1835299 I'm running Compass version 0.12.rc.0.

Comment: In that code, the `data:image/svg+xml` line is what's throwing off older versions of IE.

Comment: You must have a setting turned on that I have turned off. I'd guess you have this somewhere: `$experimental-support-for-svg: true`. I don't know anything about how the svg support works. Sorry.

Comment: To expound on the IE issue I believe @Shpigford is referring to: `Max URI length in IE8 is 32KB. In IE9 JavaScript files are supported too and the maximum size limit set to 4GB.` - http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri